# AWS Codepipeline Github Webhook not being registered through cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, github-webhook

I am trying to set AWS codepipeline and use github as the source by using cloudformation. The github repository is owned by an organization and I have admin access to it.

I was able to create webhook and successfully create entire service through codepipeline UI. But when I am trying to do same thing through Cloudformation Document, it returns error

`Webhook could not be registered with GitHub. Error cause: Not found [StatusCode: 404, Body: {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#create-a-hook"}]`

I used same credential both times (OAuth token in cloudformation and actual login popups in codepipeline UI), but when I do it through Cloudformation it failed.

I suspected my cloudformation document was the issue. But when I create my own repository, cloudformation successfully create webhook and created full codepipeline service.

Below is the summary of tests I did to understand where it went wrong.

1. Codepipeline UI. Organization Github Repo. It asked to login the github. Logged in with my admin credential => successfully created webhook and services.
2. Cloudformation. Organization Github Repo. Used OAuth Token from admin credential with `repo` and `admin:repo_hook` enabled. => Gave out error above
3. Cloudformation. Personal Github Repo. Used Oauth Token from admin credential with `repo` and `admin:repo_hook` enabled => successfully created webhook and services

The following is portion of cloudformation document where I create Webhook.

```
  AppPipelineWebhook:
    Type: 'AWS::CodePipeline::Webhook'
    Properties:
      Authentication: GITHUB_HMAC
      AuthenticationConfiguration:
        SecretToken: !Ref GitHubSecret
      Filters:
        - JsonPath: $.ref
          MatchEquals: 'refs/heads/{Branch}'
      TargetPipeline: !Ref cfSSMAutomationDev
      TargetAction: SourceAction
      Name: AppPipelineWebhook
      TargetPipelineVersion: !GetAtt cfSSMAutomationDev.Version
      RegisterWithThirdParty: true
```

So I am not sure what is wrong. My suspicion is that OAuth token requires more privilege. Does anyone have similar experience with this? Any suggestion is much appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even I was facing the same issue, by seeing codepipeline UI configuration's Repository I used

```
{
  "Configuration": {
    "Owner": "myUserName",
    "Repo": "orgname/repository-name",
  }
}
```

so cloudformation was checking for the repository myUserName/orgname/repository-name which wasn't exist.

It got solved after following the below solution:

```
{
  "Configuration": {
    "Owner": "orgname",
    "Repo": "repository-name",
  }
}
```

**private repo** -> ownerName: YourUserName 

**organisation repo** -> ownerName: OrganisationName

Comment: Did you use your "personal" access token? or does it has to be the organization's github owner's personal access token?

Comment: I used my "personal access token" as I have admin privilege.

Comment: Can we use personal access token with particular repo admin access?